# Expresión regular que busca una letra dentro de una palabra una única vez y no se repita

Tags: regex, perl

Necesito una expresión regular en Perl que me permita validar palabras que tengan en su contenido una sola letra a.

Estoy utilizando la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^(?=.*?a{1}).*$
```

Esto permite buscar cualquier letra **a** en una palabra pero no logro controlar que permita sólo una vez.

El funcionamiento de la expresión regular debe ser el siguiente:

```
Entrada: ejemplo -----> Salida: falso
Entrada: casa --------> Salida: falso
Entrada: computación ----> Salida: verdadero
```

Comment: Quité la etiqueta `Java`, porque tu pregunta especifica que se trata de Perl, no Java.

Comment: Hacer esto con expresiones regulares es bastante más complicado que hacerlo con otros métodos, ¿lo necesitas realmente? Te dejo un enlace relacionado de SO (En ingles) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186384/regex-to-match-when-a-string-is-present-twice

Comment: Muchas gracias @DanielFaro necesito resolver el ejercicio utilizando expresiones regulares, de todas maneras he revisado el enlace y me sirve de ayuda para aprender a buscar mas de una palabra dentro de una cadena.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La expresión:

```
/^[^a]*a[^a]*$/
```

funcionaría para los ejemplos que pones.

`[^a]*` encuentra cualquier cadena que no contenga una `a`, por lo que la expresión completa busca una `a` precedida por una cadena que no contiene `a` y seguida por otra cadena que tampoco contiene `a`.

---

La forma anterior funciona solo si estas buscando una única letra. Para un caso más general puedes usar el combo `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. Por ejemplo, si quieres determinar que textos contienen un solo `gato`, puedes usar:

```
/gato.*gato(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|gato/
```

De manera que:

```
"esto contiene un gato"
"gato a la vista"
```

Validan la expresión, mientras que:

```
"solo veo perros"
"dos gatos son demasiados gatos"
```

no lo hacen.

Comment: Excelente !!! Muchas gracias DavidEG funciona a la perfección. Intentaré probar (*SKIP)(*FAIL) que me puede servir para buscar todas las etiquetas en una página html.

Comment: De nada. Si necesitas parsear HTML sería mejor que utilices un módulo como https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM o https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Query para la tarea. Con expresiones regulares puede ser bastante complicado y propenso a errores.

Answer (score 1):

Con las opciones extendidas de las expresiones regulares, es muy sencillo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.14;

my @textos = qw(
    ejemplo     casa    computacion
    otra        cosa    blabla
);

for my $texto (@textos) {

    my $aes;

    $texto =~ /a(?{$aes++})(*FAIL)/;

    say "Entrada: $texto\t Salida: " . ($aes == 1 ? 'verdadero' : 'falso');
}
```

La expresión regular simplemente cuenta el número de letras 'a'. Cada vez que encuentra una, aumenta un contador, y provoca un fallo en la búsqueda ('(*FAIL)'), que hace que la expresión regular siga buscando más letras 'a'.

Solo queda comprobar si el contador es igual a 1, y sacar el texto correspondiente.

Más información en **[perldoc perlre](https://github.com/perldocES/perldoc-es/blob/master/pod/translated/perlre.pod)**, en la sección "Verbos sin argumento", primer ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Joaquin intentaré probar tu ejemplo.